# Fusion Grid Column Formatter does not parse HTML, instead it prints actual HTML in the Grid

Tags: fusioncharts

I am trying to get Fusion Grid (https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiongrid )to work from the example in the online docs. However, it does not parse the HTML. It just prints the unparsed HTML in the column.  The grid does not parse the HTML. You can see this problem in F-Series data (last column) in the example below, as well as using a column formatter, see myFunction2. None of the online docs have complete work. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
        <!-- FusionGrid JS files -->
    <script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusiongrid/latest/fusiongrid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusiongrid/latest/fusiongrid.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var schema = [
        {
          name: 'Rank',
          type: 'number',
        },
        {
          name: 'Model'
        },
        {
          name: 'Make'
        },
        {
          name: 'Units Sold',
        },
        {
          name: 'Assembly Location'
        },
        {
          name: 'Link',
          //  type: 'html'
        }
      ];
      var data = [
        [1, "F-Series", "Ford", 896526, "Claycomo, Mo.", "<a href='http://www.google.com>Edit</a>'"],
        [2, "Pickup", "Ram", 633694, "Warren, Mich."],
        [3, "Silverado", "Chevrolet", 575600, "Springfield, Ohio"],
        [4, "RAV4", "Toyota", 448071, "Georgetown, Ky."],
        [5, "CR-V", "Honda", 384168, "Greensburg, Ind."],
        [6, "Rogue", "Nissan", 350447, "Smyrna, Tenn."],
        [7, "Equinox", "Chevrolet", 346048, "Arlington, Tex."],
        [8, "Camry", "Toyota", 336978, "Georgetown, Ky."],
        [9, "Civic", "Honda", 325650, "Greensburg, Ind."],
        [10, "Corolla", "Toyota", 304850, "Blue Springs, Miss."],
        [11, "Accord", "Honda", 267567, "Marysville, Ohio"],
        [12, "Tacoma", "Toyota", 248801, "San Antonio, Tex."],
        [13, "Grand Cherokee", "Jeep", 242969, "Detroit, Mich."],
        [14, "Escape", "Ford", 241338, "Louisville, Ky."],
        [15, "Highlander", "Toyota", 239438, "Princeton, Ind."],
        [16, "Sierra", "GMC", 232325, "Flint, Mich."],
        [17, "Wrangler", "Jeep", 228032, "Toledo, Ohio"],
        [18, "Altima", "Nissan", 209183, "Smyrna, Tenn."],
        [19, "Cherokee", "Jeep", 191397, "Belvidere,     Ill."],
        [20, "Sentra", "Nissan", 184618, "Canton, Miss."],
      ];

      function myFunction2(params) {
          console.log(params.cellValue);
          let value = params.cellValue;
          let bgColor = '#ff0000';
          if (params.cellValue > 346048 && params.cellValue <= 575600) {
             bgColor = '#ffff00'
          } else if (params.cellValue > 575601) {
              bgColor = '#00ff00'
          }
          //return '{background-color:  ' + bgColor + '}';
          return ('<span style="background-color: "' + bgColor + '/>' + value + '</span>');
      }


      function render() {
        // Getting the grid-container
        var container = document.getElementById('grid-container');

        // Passing data through DataStore
        var dataStore = new FusionGrid.DataStore();
        var dataTable = dataStore.createDataTable(data, schema, {enableIndex: false });
        var grid = new FusionGrid(container, dataTable, 
        {
          defaultColumnOptions: {
            searchable: true,
            filter: {
              enable: true,
              type: "conditional"
            },
          },
            columns: [
            {
              field: 'Rank' ,
            },
            {
              field: 'Model' ,
            },
            {
              field: 'Make' ,
            },
            {
              field: 'Units Sold',
              type: 'number',
              formatter: myFunction2,
            },
            {
              field: 'Assembly Location',
            },
            {
              field: 'Link',
              // type: 'html'
            }
          ],
        });

        // Render the grid
        grid.render();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="render()">
    <h1>Hello from FusionGrid!</h1>
    <div id="grid-container" style="width: 100%; height: 450px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would expect that <span style="background-color: would be evaluated to actual HTML output, not unprocessed HTML

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cesar for finding a solution: use a template with HTML type, not a formatter, as was incorrectly shown in the online documentation:

```
   {
              field: 'Units Sold',
              type: 'html',
              template: myFunction2,
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

use type html and template

```
  {
          field: 'Units Sold',
          type: 'html',
          template: myFunction2
  }
```

Comment: Can we customization template with react ?
Can we use template as react function and automatically re-rendring update on data and component ?